# May I know which are those contexts in which state verbs are used in progressive forms?

Tags: usage

I heard the following news a while ago.

> 59 percent of the voters are wanting Mr Modi to be the next PM of the nation.

What is the justification for the usage "wanting"?

Comment: A source would be helpful here. This would not be a common locution in the US, but there are regional differences in English usage.

Comment: "wanting" is "want" over some period of time. "voters *want* Mr Modi" means today, but "voters *are wanting* Mr Modi" means continuously over some period of time.

Comment: Was this Indian English?  *Are wanting* wouldn't work in American or British English.

Comment: On the contrary, it can work in British English, to convey that _right now, today_ 59% of voters want him, but last week there were nothing like that many, and it may be very different again next week. I don't know about AmE.

Comment: Yes, the progressive could be used in AmE and yes, it conveys the idea of right now. However, here, I think it is more Indian English.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question.  The short answer is that simple present is much more common in written English.  (Indeed, an attempt to get stats from Google Ngrams failed because neither “I’m wanting” nor “I am wanting” is even common enough to index.)

When I’m describing a situation that never changes, or what I normally do, I always use simple present. When I describe something that’s only true for a short interval of time, I always use the present progressive.  In most situations, which don’t fall cleanly into one or the other, I use either.

This applies to state verbs such as *hope*, *want* and *expect*, for the most part.  I would probably say, “I expect my elected representatives to share my values,” and not “I’m expecting,” because that’s something that’s always true.  I would probably say, “Right now, I’m still expecting my party to lose narrowly, but another good poll could change my mind,” because that’s a state I’m in provisionally and temporarily.  Similarly, I would say something like, “I normally **go** for a morning walk, but because it’s so hot, I **am staying** home today.”  The first verb I highlighted is a recurring, habitual action, and the second is a temporary, time-limited one.  (And native speakers don’t say “it ***is being** so hot,” even though we might use other progressive-tense verbs in the same context.)  If I could add “always,” “normally” or “usually” without changing the meaning, the verb should probably be in the simple present.  If I could add “for now” or “at the moment” without changing the meaning, the verb should probably be in the present progressive.  In most cases, though, I could say it either way.

I probably wouldn’t say, “they’re wanting” something here.  I’m not sure exactly why, but it might be a legacy of how *wanting* used to mean inadequate, deficient or insufficient, as in the quote, “You have been weighed in the balances, and found wanting.”  It’s not that uncommon to hear song lyrics like, “She’s wanting me less and I’m wanting her more,” though.  (Some of the comments claim that this is different in India, where the article you cited is from.)

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to "I am loving it", which was used in a commercial. Language changes over time and sometimes ungrammatical usage becomes common, but I wouldn't recommend it in newspaper articles.